# How to apply constraints to drawn image in CGRect inside a parent image

Tags: ios, swift

I have a CGRect with an image inside it that I plotted to specifically live in a certain area of a parent image. I'm using a JSON file that will give me x and y coordinates relative to the parent image. My question is, after drawing this smaller image onto the parent image, how can I then apply auto layout to the smaller image? I want to be able to reference the smaller image to constrain other images to it and apply width/height constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-layout operates on views. If you want to use auto-layout to position a smaller image on top of a larger image, you would need both of them to be views.

Thus, you could make both UIImageViews, and then apply auto layout anchors to position the smaller image (view) on top of the larger.

Comment: Agreed! Is there anyway to use auto layout to plot UIImageViews by giving them custom X, Y coordinates?

Comment: You can use x and y center anchors.